# Criando processos com fork

Tags: c, c++, processo

Estou criando uma sequencia de processos através do comando `fork`, mas quando fui listar os processos gerados pelo código, me deparei que havia uma quantidade maior do que eu havia criado. Porque disso?

> Ao fazer **10** `forks` foram gerados **1024** processos.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, const char **argv){
    int fork_id[10];
    int x;
    for(x=0; x<10; x++){
        fork_id[x] = fork();
        if(!fork_id){
            execl("/usr/bin/sleep", "5", NULL);
        }
    }

    sleep(10);

    return 0;
}
```

Para verificar a quantidade de processos utilizei o `ps`:

```
ps aux | grep test_fork | grep -v grep | wc -l
```

Comment: ao invés desse pipeline você poderia ter usado "pgrep -c test_fork" :)

Comment: é uma boa idéia tbm, eu não sabia como usar o pgrep mas vou procurar um pouco sobre ele

Comment: depois que você aprende sobre pgrep e pkill seus problemas acabaram :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Na realidade a tua solução está a gerar 2^10 processos (já que cada filho com x=n
vai criar ainda netos(com x=n+1 ... x=10), e estes bisnetos, etc).

Propunha:

```
int main () {
    int i, pid;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        pid = fork();
        if (pid != 0) { //se sou o processo filho: saio do ciclo!
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("I am : (i=%d),(pid=%d) mypid=%d\n",i, pid, getpid());
    return 0;
}
```

Ou seja: quando é feito o `fork()` o valor retornado vai permitir
distinguir entre pai (0) e filho (número do processo).
Para evitar netos, juntamos uma instrução que diz:

```
Se eu sou o filho, sai do ciclo para não haver netos...
```

o que dá:

```
I am : (i=0),(pid=25794) mypid=25793
I am : (i=1),(pid=25795) mypid=25794
I am : (i=2),(pid=25796) mypid=25795
I am : (i=3),(pid=25797) mypid=25796
I am : (i=4),(pid=25798) mypid=25797
I am : (i=5),(pid=25799) mypid=25798
I am : (i=6),(pid=25800) mypid=25799
I am : (i=7),(pid=25801) mypid=25800
I am : (i=8),(pid=25802) mypid=25801
I am : (i=9),(pid=25803) mypid=25802
I am : (i=10),(pid=0) mypid=25803
```

Comment: Muito boa resposta! +1 Mas era bom também explicar o que a verificação de `pid == 0` faz, não? :)

Comment: @LuizVieira, obrigado mais uma vez. Resolvi inverter a lógica para ser mais fácil de explicar...